# Cases in “Das sind meine Mutter und mein Vater”

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

*Mutter* and *Vater* being the objects of the sentence, shouldn’t the preposition (?) *mein* for Vater change to *meinen*?

Meaning, why is it only correct to say:

> Das ist meinen Tisch.

but not correct to say the following?

> Das sind meine Mutter und *meinen* Vater.

Comment: 'das ist meinen Tisch' is not correct. It should be 'das ist mein Tisch'.

Comment: Downvoters kindly explain

Comment: I guess people downvoted (action I don't agree with) because you made some wrong assumptions. To avoid those downvotes, you could just check (1) which kind of word *mein* is (e.g. in Wiktionary) and (2) your first sentence was wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the opportunity to improve. Sorry to be a dreaded help vampire.

Comment: German doesn't have the (English) heuristic "inflection is for objects". It has a richer set of inflectional cases, and different kinds of complements use different cases. "sein" happens to take the nominative (base form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not correct** to say

> Das ist meinen Tisch.

**Correctly**, it always has to be

> Das ist mein Tisch.

Therefore, also the sentences

> Das sind meine Mutter und mein Vater.
>
> Das ist mein Vater.
>
> Das ist meine Mutter.

are **correct.**

---

*Mein*, *meine*, *meiner* [and so on] are possessive pronouns.

```
Kasus       Maskulinum     Femininum    Neutrum     Plural
Nominativ   meiner         meine        meins       meine
Akkusativ   meinen         meine        meins       meine
Dativ       meinem         meiner       meinem      meinen
Genitiv     meines         meiner       meines      meiner
```

Comment: So even though `meine` looks like `eine` and `kleine` it behaves differently because it is "possessive" correct? By the same token `deine` etc also work similarly?

Comment: _deine_ works like _meine_, _seine_, _ihre_ and other possessive pronouns. _kleine_ is an adjective and is [inflected differently](http://www.deutschonline.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm). _eine_ is an indefinite article and behaves like possessive pronouns.

Answer (score 9):

As jera has explained, the correct sentences are

> Das sind meine Mutter and mein Vater

and

> Das ist mein Tisch

That said, I would like to add something to help you understand why.

I think you are getting confused with the accusative because you are following a simple (and unfortunately misleading) rule: if it answers the question "Who(m)? What?" then it is accusative.

For example, let's take the sentence "I eat an apple". You can think: "I eat *what*? An apple". So "an apple" must be the object, and thus it's accusative, so the translation in German is: "Ich esse einen Apfel". "Einen" is clearly accusative, and it is correct. But here comes the tricky part: this doesn't work with the verb "to be".

With respect to "This is a table", if you reason like this you will think "This is *what*?", and since "A table" is the answer, you will conclude it must be accusative. Unfortunately, it's wrong!

**The golden rule is that with the verb "to be" (sein) you never have the accusative, it's always nominative.**

Thus, "Mutter" and "Vater" in that sentence are not the *objects*. They are "[predicative nominals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar)#Predicates_in_traditional_grammar)".

Answer (score 4):

You start from the assumption that the part after *ist* is the direct object of the sentence, but that assumption is wrong. Consequently, the conclusion that *Mutter*, *Vater*, *Tisch* should be accusative is also wrong.

One important role of the verb *sein* is that of the [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29): It links the subject to a complement, which may be called *subject complement*, *predicative complement* or *subject predicative*. This complement, at least in German, is in the same case as the subject, i.e. in nominative.

Therefore, the only correct form of both sentences from the question is:

> Das ist mein Tisch.
>   Das sind meine Mutter und mein Vater.

Canoo.net has a page with [more details on complements](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzglied/Praedikat/Praedikativ.html?lang=en) (including subject complements and object complements).